# How to convert date time from ISO Format to UTC time zone?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, utc, iso8601

I am using `moment.js`, and I want to convert from ISO Format date time to UTC time zone.

I can convert from local time to UTC+ISOformat, but I am not able to convert ISO format to UTC time zone.

Input:

```
2018-03-22T00:00:00Z
```

Expected output:

date should be in UTC time zone. If I calculate the it should be:

```
22018-03-21T18:30:00Z
```

1. First I want to convert into ISO, After that convert into UTC**.

***Not able to Converted local date time to ISO then UTC***

We can convert into string, But from ISO format can convert or not?

**Fox example:**  I want to convert `ISODATE(2018-03-22T00:00:00Z)` into UTC time zone.

```
function toISO(dt) {
  return moment(dt).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss") + "Z";
}
var date = new Date();
var isoDate= toISO(date)
```

***Direct we can convert***

```
function toISOWithUtc(dt) {
      return moment(dt).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss") + "Z";
}
var date = new Date();
toISO(date)
```

Comment: Please include inputs and expected outputs for each input.

Comment: @Igor  convert into UTC.. 2018-03-22T00:00:00Z

Comment: Let me rephrase: **[edit] your question, include inputs and corresponding expected outputs**. If you really want to be helpful to those looking at the question do it as if you were writing unit tests.

Comment: *How* is `2018-03-22T00:00:00Z` not in "date should be in UTC time zone"?  Again, write it as if you were writing a unit test. What is the type you are checking and what should its value be? At the moment it is still very unclear what you are actually asking/needing.

Comment: `2018-03-22T00:00:00Z` is not a local time, the `Z` at the end means the timezone is UTC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `2018-03-22T00:00:00Z` and `2018-03-21T18:30:00Z` **already are in UTC**.

Note the `Z` in the end? [This means that the date is in UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)). It's not a hardcoded letter that you can just append to the end - it has a specific meaning, it tells that the date/time is in UTC.

If you want to convert that UTC date to another timezone (I'm guessing that's what you want), you can use [moment.tz](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/):

```
// convert UTC 2018-03-22T00:00:00Z to Asia/Kolkata timezone
moment.tz('2018-03-22T00:00:00Z','Asia/Kolkata')
```

Just change the timezone name to the one you want to convert.

And calling `format()` will give you the converted date/time in ISO8601 format:

```
moment.tz('2018-03-22T00:00:00Z','Asia/Kolkata').format() // 2018-03-22T05:30:00+05:30
```

Note that the offset changed from `Z` to `+05:30`. This means that the date/time above is 5 hours and 30 minutes ahead UTC, which is the result of converting `2018-03-22T00:00:00Z` to Kolkata's timezone.

**Note:** I think you're mistaking the concepts here.

[UTC is a time standard](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html). It defines things like the current date/time accross the world, it uses atomic clocks to make sure everybody on Earth are synchronized, and [timezones are all based on offsets from UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets).

[ISO8601 is a standard for exchanging date/time-related data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). It defines **formats** (text representations of dates). A date/time can be in ISO format, **regardless of being in UTC or not**.

That's why *"convert from UTC to ISO"* (or vice-versa) makes no sense at all.

Comment: There two way to convert..   function toISO(dt) {
      return moment(dt).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss") + "Z";
    }
    function toISOWithUtc(dt) {
      return moment(dt).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss") + "Z";
    }

Comment: First toISO only convert into ISO Format not in UTC. Second one convert into UTC and ISO

Comment: 1- If you put a `Z` in the end, it means that the date is in UTC - check the link in the answer above. 2- UTC is a time standard to define things like "current time" and used by timezones to define their local times in all parts of the world, while ISO8601 defines formats (text representations for dates). Convert UTC to ISO makes no sense at all: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss" is a ISO format, regardless of being in UTC or not.

Comment: yes, you are correct. I already converted to UTC with wrong way. Thanks pist